# getting null pointer in onLocationChanged method for context

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am new to Android. I want to show a Toast or Snackbar in the `onLocationChanged` method, but I am getting a `NullPointerException` in this method for the context. How can I solve this?

```
private void displayTost(Location location)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed......",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Log output:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4044)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd.activities.BumpdActivity.displayTost(BumpdActivity.java:323)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd.activities.BumpdActivity.onLocationChanged(BumpdActivity.java:282)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:279)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:208)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
11-19 12:43:35.944 23614-23614/com.vaidya.prasad.bumpd E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your code and logcat properly first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u try to  get Context() in a class which doesn't extends activity or appcompactactivity like adapter class in recycler view then just write a parametrized constructer which accept Context as a parameter from class which extends activity .& then just pass context to adapter class by creating object of it.
like below code
 `public RVAdapter(Context contexts, List<quiz>quizList) { this.mContext = contexts; this.quizList=quizList; }`
& in activity just pass context as
RVAdapter adapter=new RVAdapter(this,qw);

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the classname of your Listener provided it `extends Activity implements LocationListener`, From your logcat I can guess the Activity name is BumpdActivity, so why don't you try below line..

```
Toast.makeText(BumpdActivity.this,"Location changed......",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If that doesn't work please share your class..

Comment: I would try this one. Its easy to read and there is no reason to use `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()` if you call `Toast.makeText` in your Activity (BumpdActivity).

Comment: I have already tried getApplicationContext(),getBaseContext(),BumpedActivity.this. but nothing any work.please try to resolve it

Comment: Does your class extends Activity class ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void displayTost() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location changed......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

PS : post relevant codes for using `Location location` in your above method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location changed......",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

getApplicationContext()
return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process.

Answer (score 0):

Enter you class name dot this inplace of context or pass a context argument like this.

```
private void displayTost(Context context, Location location)
{
    Toast.makeText(context,"Location changed......",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```